# Custom WP_Query won't print items to page, even though it contains the expected data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WP_Query which contains data that I want to loop over on the page:

```
$query_posts_for_board_game = new WP_Query(get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => $mm_custom_post_types,
    'numberposts' => 20,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => array('board_game', 'board_games'),
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
)));
```

When I var_dump it I can see that it has the data in the `query` and `query_vars` properties but when I loop over it using the `$query_posts_for_board_game->have_posts()` method nothing is output. This code simply prints the else block.

```
<?php if($query_posts_for_board_game->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ($query_posts_for_board_game->have_posts()) : $query_posts_for_board_game->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/layouts/content', 'b1' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/layouts/content-none' ); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

If I remove the call to `WP_Query` and just use `get_posts` I'm able to loop over it with a standard for loop, but then the nested templates can't take advantage of `$post` like they would with a normal loop:

```
<?php
    // If there are posts
    if ($posts_for_board_game) :
        // Loop the posts
        foreach ($posts_for_board_game as $board_game_post) :
    ?>
        <?php echo $board_game_post->post_title . '<br />'; ?>
    <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I seem to recall that this is because my custom query isn’t part of “the query”. Is there a way I can override “the query” so that my content can be output? Can I simply move my query further down the page after the other items are output?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I'm sort of shocked that it was as easy as this.

I left the WP_Query in place, just like in the first query above. Then in my loop I simply changed the name of the iterator to `$post` and it started working. Here's the complete code for anyone else who has this question.

```
$query_posts_for_board_game = new WP_Query(get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => $mm_custom_post_types,
    'numberposts' => 20,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => array('board_game', 'board_games'),
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
)));
$posts_for_board_games = $query_posts_for_board_game->query;
```

and the output:

```
<?php if($posts_for_board_games): ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts_for_board_games as $post): ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/layouts/content', 'b1' ); ?>
    <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/layouts/content-none' ); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

I'm a little annoyed that I had to use an intermediate variable, to get at the query contents, but I'm fine with this code.